# CUDA program ignores CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES variable?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I'm using CUDA 7.5 on a machine with Ubuntu Server 14.04 and 3 GPUs: 2x Tesla K20C and 1x GeForce GT 630. I've tried to set the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to the according IDs so that the code only runs on both of the Tesla GPUs. For some reason, the program seems to ignore the variable and tries to run the code on all 3 GPUs, which results in an error.

So far, I've tried to set the variable in `/etc/environment` and also in the `bash.bashrc` file (rebooted afterwards). When using `echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`, the correct values are shown. Also, when starting the program remotely from NSight via SSH with the environment variable set accordingly, the execution works as intended and only uses the 2 Tesla GPUs. But when I'm starting the program locally (via terminal or via Gearman worker from a web interface), the environmental variable seems to be ignored.

As a workaround, I'm using `setenv("CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES","0,2",1)` within the code. But that makes my program non-portable.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rubber duck debugging really works.

Turns out it is enough to use unsetenv before calling cuInit or cudaSetDevice, and the initial value of environmetal variable will be ignored.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
  int x;
  unsetenv("CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES");
  cuInit(0);
  // Now we see all the devices on machine
  cuDeviceGetCount(&x);
  printf("%d\n",x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've read that one already. It's doing the opposite of what I want. I specifically want the programm to **not** ignore the variable. This only tells me how to use all GPUs in any case.